# System of second-order differential equations to system of first-order differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

We need to convert the following system of 2nd-order DE into a system of 1st-order DE:

$$3y_1''+6y_1-2y_2=0$$
$$y_2''-2y_1+2y_2=0$$

Then using the following IVPs: $y_1(0)=0, y_1'(0)=0, y_2(0)=1, y_2'(0)=0$, solve the system with Laplace transforms.

Comment: This is the first time I've seen a question like this. I have been searching the internet for clues to this but there are only the ones that I am comfortable with, which is just converting two first-order system into a second order, or vice versa. I have no trouble doing  the Laplace afterwards, I'm just confused about the conversion. You can show me a simpler example of this without telling me the answer if you really concern I don't try it myself. All I want is just clues/hints to do the conversion. Thanks.

Comment: With no Laplace transform: Looking for solutions of the pair of differential equations of the form $$(y_1(x),y_2(x))=(c_1e^{ux},c_2e^{ux})$$
yields the system $$3(u^2+1)c_1=2c_2\qquad(u^2+2)c_2=2c_1$$ This has nonzero solutions $(c_1,c_2)$ if and only if $$3(u^2+1)(u^2+2)=4$$
that is, $$u=\pm i\frac{\sqrt{54\pm\sqrt{19}}}6$$ Each of these four values $u$ yields a particular solution $$(y_1(x),y_2(x))=(2e^{ux},3(u^2+1)e^{ux})$$ hence the general solution of the system is $$y_1(x)=2\sum_uc_ue^{ux}\qquad y_2(x)=3\sum_uc_u(u^2+1)e^{ux}$$ for four constants $c_u$ whose values are determined ...

Comment: ...  by the initial conditions, which yield $$\sum_uc_u=\sum_uc_uu=\sum_uc_uu(u^2+1)=0\qquad 3\sum_uc_u(u^2+1)=1$$ which are equivalent to $$\sum_uc_u=\sum_uc_uu=\sum_uc_uu^3=0\qquad\sum_uc_uu^2=\frac13$$ This is a Vandermonde linear system whose determinant is nonzero hence it has a unique solution $(c_u)$ and you are done. The idea behind all this is that one is looking at a linear system $$y'(x)=Ay(x)$$ with $$y(x)=\begin{pmatrix}y'_1(x)\\ y'_2(x)\\ y_1(x)\\ y_2(x)\end{pmatrix}\qquad A=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&-2&\frac23\\ 0&0&2&-2\\ 1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: ... and the four complex numbers $u$ above are the eigenvalues of $A$. Thus, simply the usual case.